# Issue in using Twitter API from Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, twitter

I am new bee to twitter API and MongoDb. I am trying out a ruby example from the book 'MongoDb In Action', Chapter-3 which connects to Twitter and gets feeds based on given tags. I have done the ruby set up as suggested. I am getting the following exception, which I think is related to ruby set up. Any hint is highly appreciated.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': execution expired (Twitter::Error::ClientError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:75:in `perform_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb:14:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:247:in `run_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:112:in `post'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/client.rb:108:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/client.rb:72:in `post'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:82:in `object_from_response'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/api/oauth.rb:24:in `token'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/client.rb:96:in `block in request_setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:102:in `block in get'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:243:in `block in run_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:258:in `block in build_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request.rb:35:in `block in create'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request.rb:34:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request.rb:34:in `create'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:254:in `build_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:239:in `run_request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:100:in `get'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/client.rb:108:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/client.rb:66:in `get'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:82:in `object_from_response'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter/api/search.rb:32:in `search'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.8.1/lib/twitter.rb:60:in `method_missing'
    from /home/hadoop/archiver.rb:27:in `save_tweets_for'
    from /home/hadoop/archiver.rb:21:in `update'
    from update.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
    from update.rb:3:in `each'
    from update.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you are reading was printed in 2011 and appears to use APIv1 which has recently been depreciated by twitter.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#17750

You'll need to set up oauth and I suggest you start with the twitter gem documentation.

https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Comment: Thanks you very much. Based on your directions I figured out the required changes and it is working now.